# Why is `dotnet --version` returning "Unknown Option"?

Tags: .net-core

When I run `dotnet --version` from the command line to see which version I have installed it tells me "Unknown Version" What am I doing wrong here? I installed `DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe` and `dotnet-dev-win-x64.1.0.0-preview2-1-003177.exe` sdk. I imagine I went wrong somewhere around here.

[image: DotNet Error]

Comment: The `Usage` details you've included don't state that there is a `--version` option. What makes you think it's a supported argument?

Comment: @AndyLamb I was looking at this article. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567353/how-to-determine-if-netcore-is-installed I'm trying to figure out what to plug into my project.json

Comment: Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet