# Get list of all .NET (Core) versions used on a IIS server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

> Note: this question is *not* about *.NET Framework* versions

Given a Windows server with multiple versions of

- Microsoft .NET Core
- Microsoft .NET Core Runtime
- Microsoft ASP.NET Core - Shared framework
  in Programs and features.

And several IIS websites targeting various of those versions.

What's a way to list all currently used .NET (Core) versions across all deployed websites?

Purpose: efficient cleanup of outdated and unsupported .NET versions.

Comment: There is. When I developed ASP.NET Core Diagnostics in Jexus Manager, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html the basic algorithm for a single site/application is there. But roll-forward was not considered, so you still need to improve the code. Some hints are there in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44240029/determine-which-net-core-runtime-is-needed

Comment: In theory, it can be done. usually, these information are contained in web.config. what you need to do is to list them all at once, of course, you can also do it through some code or plugins. you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/483479/how-to-check-aspnet-version-of-the-website.html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/483479/how-to-check-aspnet-version-of-the-website.html).