# Partial view Menu - Send info to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

That's how I try to get a view that includes a class with. The way I get it on it is by writing:

```
@Html.Partial("View/ViewBar_Info/Menu")
```

[image: See how my view/controlle looks out]

If I'm doing an ordinary MVC view, I can do that. but that's because I have to get the menu that is being controlled via the database. Therefore, I try to do this here.

How can I call that view?

[image: Error here]

Error Text:

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Generated Code One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure
>   that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the
>   'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.

**Update EIDT:**

I make this from _Layout.cshtml

```
@Html.Partial("View/ViewBar_Info/Menu.cshtml")
```

in the Menu.cshtml:

```
@page
@model NewWebsite_SITE_2018.Pages.View.ViewBar_Info.MenuModel

@foreach (var item in Model.GetListMenu)
{
    <a>@item.Name</a>
}
```

Error now its:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'NewWebsite_SITE_2018.Pages.IndexModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'NewWebsite_SITE_2018.Pages.View.ViewBar_Info.MenuModel'.

What I'm trying to do is in my layout, so I'll call my menu so come on the single page.

Comment: You should copy the error message and paste it into your question

Comment: i have add this now @CodeNotFound

Comment: Just for clarification, is that project has reference to mentioned `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` package? Have you already done anything said in error message?

Comment: @J Petersen, what is you dotnet version?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567353/how-to-determine-if-netcore-is-installed

Comment: @itikhomi 2.0 .net core. i have the new version of VS

Comment: @J Petersen, if you have really 2.0.0, you should update it to 2.0.3 manualy  or via VS, and then update packages of your projects. It seams you get razor library precompilation issue that has been before 2.0.3

Comment: What is a file you think I should look at? @itikhomi

Comment: open cmd and run "dotnet --version"

Comment: i have 2.0.3 :)

Comment: Did your Microsoft.AspNetCore.All are 2.0.3 in your project?

Comment: Yes i have Microsoft.AspNetCore.All @itikhomi

Comment: Is Microsoft.AspNetCore.All are 2.0.3 version?

Comment: Yea this a version 2.0.3

Comment: Please provide Menu.cshtml

Comment: same error for this. @itikhomi

Comment: Can you please copy code of Menu.cshtml and paste it to question?

Comment: i have update now @itikhomi

Comment: @JPetersen check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem has been in Razor precompilation issue that fixed in 2.0.3
https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/2981

Second

When you call your partical you should send correct model to it if you not send razor try to send current model of view

send existed model

`@Html.Partial("View/ViewBar_Info/Menu.cshtml", yourMenuModel)`

or create new

`@Html.Partial("View/ViewBar_Info/Menu.cshtml", new NewWebsite_SITE_2018.Pages.View.ViewBar_Info.MenuModel())`

or modify your view for non required model

```
@{
var menuModel = new NewWebsite_SITE_2018.Pages.View.ViewBar_Info.MenuModel();
}

@foreach (var item in menuModel.GetListMenu)
{
    <a>@item.Name</a>
}
```

Comment: Yes ok, I learned something new but my next problem is just that db in my menu file is going to give trouble. `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context' of 'MenuModel.MenuModel(DBContext)'`