# inno setup check dotnet core is installed

Tags: .net, .net-core, inno-setup

Inno setup check dotnet core is installed.
Couldn't find REG_DWORD for .net core in Registry Editor. 
Could someone help me in locating the .net core version in Registry Editor to check if .net core is installed

Comment: https://www.aaflalo.me/2020/06/net-core-detection-in-inno-setup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently running `dotnet --version` or `dotnet --info` is probably the simplest way.
I guess, since .net core can be installed anywhere (Mac, Linux, Windows) they decided to stick with CLI.

I've seen people using `HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\...` to check a version but I believe this is not a consistent solution across .net core versions, OS versions, 32bit and 64bit, etc, so **try to avoid using Registry**

You can also programmatically look up the `dotnet` folder in `Program Files`. If it's there, go to the `host/fxr` sub directory and find the latest version there i.e.

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\*VERSION*\hostfxr.dll`

Btw, `hostfxr.dll` library exposes an export `hostfxr_get_available_sdks`. You can load the library and call this API (no setup necessary) to get the list of installed SDKs - this is similar to `dotnet --info`.

Also, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567353/how-to-determine-if-net-core-is-installed) - you can find more ways of check .net core version.

I hope it helps

Comment: Ok, this shows how *you* can check if the runtime is installed, but now how *InnoSetup* can check if the runtime is installed.  Can you provide a code example showing how to, for instance, use `dotnet --info`?  That's the part I'm struggling with, not the command itself. It's integrating that command and its output into my script/setup.